# Selection by timestamp

Tags: solidity

Iam trying to select values by timestamp like a "unique id"
iam using that code and iam using that compiler 0.8.17 :

.sol

```
contract Values{
    address  owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    event valeuArrtransfer(uint256 timestamp,string valeu1,string valeu2,string valeu3,string valeu4,string valeu5,string valeu6);

    struct valeuArr{   
        string valeu1;
        string valeu2;
        string valeu3;
        string valeu4;
        string valeu5;
        string valeu6;
        uint256 timestamp;
    }
    
    mapping(uint => valeuArr) valeuap;
    
    valeuArr[] valeuArR;

    function setvale (string memory valeu1,string memory valeu2,string memory valeu3,string memory valeu4,string memory valeu5,string memory valeu6) public {
        valeuap.push(
            valeuArr(
                    valeu1,
                    valeu2,
                    valeu3,
                    valeu4,
                    valeu5,
                    valeu6,
                    block.timestamp
            )
        );

}

function getAllArr() public view returns(valeuArr[] memory) {
        return valeuArR;
    }
    function getAllArr2(uint256 timestamp) public view returns(string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory) {
        return (
                valeuap[timestamp].valeu2,
                    valeuap[timestamp].valeu3,
                    valeuap[timestamp].valeu4,
                    valeuap[timestamp].valeu5,
                    valeuap[timestamp].valeu6,
                    valeuap[timestamp].valeu7
                    );
    }

    }
```

In Remix Ide when iam trying  that "function getAllkturia2".
Iam  taking  empty values
what can i do for take values  by timestamp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setter function (`setkturia()`) pushes data into the array (`kturiaupoPinakas`) that has incremental keys - not the timestamp keys.

The getter function (`getAllkturia2()`) reads not from the array - but from the mapping (`kturiap`), which is not filled anywhere in the code.

In order to read from the mapping, you need to fill it first.

Expanding on your existing code, this is the updated setter function that fills both the array and the mapping.

```
function setkturia(string memory dhmos,string memory fek,string memory apof,string memory dieuth,string memory status,string memory cid) public {
    kturiapinakas memory value = kturiapinakas(
        dhmos,
        fek,
        apof,
        dieuth,
        status,
        cid,
        block.timestamp
    );
    kturiaupoPinakas.push(value);
    kturiap[block.timestamp] = value;
}
```